# generate embed code for imgur

Tags: php, imgur

When you see an image or album on imgur, you can get its embed code via "..."->share/embed. My goal would be to generate that from any imgur URL. It's almost done but an exception.

Some imgur URL has a json response if you extends with a ".json" :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAb8X.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAb8X.jpg.json ("hash":"imKf8NX")

Above, I can get the hash and I can generate the embed code easily.
**Here is another imgur URL which I can't handle:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi3na.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi3na.jpg.json (throws a 404 instead of any useful data)

Is there any method (for PHP) or URL, imgur API endpoint that could give me useful information so I would dig for its hash?

thank you for advance!